# Object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a function like this

```
public void GetTablesWithUpperCaseName()
{
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
   objConnectionString.DataSource = txtHost.Text;
   objConnectionString.UserID = txtUsername.Text;
   objConnectionString.Password = txtPassword.Text;
   objConnectionString.InitialCatalog = Convert.ToString(cmbDatabases.SelectedValue);

   SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(objConnectionString.ConnectionString);

   //To Open the connection.
   sConnection.Open();

   //Query to select table_names that have their names in uppercase letters.
   string selectTablesWithUppercaseName = @"SELECT 
                                              NAME
                                            FROM 
                                              sysobjects 
                                            WHERE 
                                              UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = name COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN 
                                              AND 
                                                 OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsTable')=1
                                              AND 
                                                 OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsMSShipped')=0 ";
   //Create the command object
   SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectTablesWithUppercaseName, sConnection);

   try
   {
       //Create the dataset
       DataSet dsListOfTablesWithUppercaseName = new DataSet("sysobjects");

       //Create the dataadapter object
       SqlDataAdapter sDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTablesWithUppercaseName, sConnection);

       //Provides the master mapping between the sourcr table and system.data.datatable
       sDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "sysobjects");

       //Fill the dataset
       sDataAdapter.Fill(dsListOfTablesWithUppercaseName);

       //Bind the result combobox with foreign key table names
       DataViewManager dvmListOfForeignKeys = dsListOfTablesWithUppercaseName.DefaultViewManager;
       dgResultView.DataSource = dsListOfTablesWithUppercaseName.Tables["sysobjects"];
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
        EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
        log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
        log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
       //If connection is not closed then close the connection
       if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
          sConnection.Close();
       }
    }
 }
```

And another function for counting the rows generated from the previous functions. But this function

> Null Reference Exception or Object
>   reference not set to an instance of
>   object..

Can anyone help me in this... why it is catching error only for the functions above and working fine for all other similar functions.

```
private void UpdateLabelText()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    objConnectionString.DataSource = txtHost.Text;
    objConnectionString.UserID = txtUsername.Text;
    objConnectionString.Password = txtPassword.Text;
    objConnectionString.InitialCatalog = Convert.ToString(cmbDatabases.SelectedValue);

    SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(objConnectionString.ConnectionString);

    //To Open the connection.
    sConnection.Open();

    try
    {
        int SelectedCellTotal = 0;
        int counter;

        // Iterate through the SelectedCells collection and sum up the values.
        for(counter = 0;counter < (dgResultView.SelectedCells.Count);counter++)
        {
            if(dgResultView.SelectedCells[counter].FormattedValueType == Type.GetType("System.String"))
            {
                 string value = null;

                 // If the cell contains a value that has not been commited,
                 if(dgResultView.IsCurrentCellDirty == true)
                 {
                    value = dgResultView.SelectedCells[counter].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    value = dgResultView.SelectedCells[counter].FormattedValue.ToString();
                 }
                 if(value != null)
                 {
                    // Ignore cells in the Description column.
                    if(dgResultView.SelectedCells[counter].ColumnIndex != dgResultView.Columns["TABLE_NAME"].Index)
                    {
                       if(value.Length != 0)
                       {
                          SelectedCellTotal += int.Parse(value);
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
            }

            // Set the labels to reflect the current state of the DataGridView.
            lblDisplay.Text = "There are Total " + dgResultView.RowCount + cmbOperations.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //If connection is not closed then close the connection
            if(sConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also the lblDisplay.Text is not taking proper spaces.

Waiting for reply

Comment: You've provided a lot of code... which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: That (wall of) code is starting to look familiar.

Comment: And why do you even create and open a `SqlConnection` in your second method?? You're not using it anywhere......

Comment: Regarding the spaces in lblDisplay: you have to add space after the count: `lblDisplay.Text = "There are Total " + dgResultView.RowCount + " " + cmbOperations.SelectedItem.ToString();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I don't really have an answer why you're getting a "null reference exception" - but a few points to throw in, nonetheless:

- I would use `sys.tables` instead of `sysobjects` and having to specify what type of object to query for
- **ALWAYS** put your disposable `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(.....) { ...... }` blocks. That way, you won't need any `finally {..}` blocks, and .NET will take care of properly disposing of those objects when they're no longer needed
- why do you use a `DataSet` when you only have a single table inside?? That's just unnecessary overhead - use a `DataTable` instead!
- don't open the `SqlConnection` that early - wait 'til the very last moment, open it, execute query, close it again right away
- actually, when using the `SqlDataAdapter`, you don't need to open the `SqlConnection` yourself at all - the `SqlDataAdapter` will do that for you (and close it again after it is done reading the data)
- do **not** mix the retrieval of the data from the database with the binding to the UI element - this is a very bad practice. From the `GetTablesWithUpperCaseName` method, you should return something (like a `DataTable`) to the caller (the UI) and let the UI handle the binding process
- along the same lines: that method should **not** be grabbing stuff from UI elements (like text boxes) itself - pass in those values as method parameters, to get a cleaner code - one that you *might* actually be able to reuse in another project some day

This is how I think your first method ought to look like

```
    public DataTable GetTablesWithUpperCaseName(string server, string database, 
                                                string username, string password)
    {
        // Create the datatable
        DataTable dtListOfTablesWithUppercaseName = new DataTable("tableNames");

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder objConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        objConnectionString.DataSource = server;;
        objConnectionString.UserID = username;
        objConnectionString.Password = password;
        objConnectionString.InitialCatalog = database;

        // Define the Query against sys.tables - much easier and cleaner!
        string selectTablesWithUppercaseName =
            "SELECT NAME FROM sys.tables WHERE UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = name COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AND is_msshipped = 0";

        // put your SqlConnection and SqlCommand into using blocks!
        using (SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(objConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand(selectTablesWithUppercaseName, sConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the dataadapter object
                SqlDataAdapter sDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTablesWithUppercaseName, sConnection);

                // Fill the datatable - no need to open the connection, the SqlDataAdapter will do that all by itself 
                // (and also close it again after it is done)
                sDataAdapter.Fill(dtListOfTablesWithUppercaseName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
                EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
                log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
                log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // return the data table to the caller
        return dtListOfTablesWithUppercaseName;
    }
```